# SDCard frequently unmounts itself with HTC One V

Tags: sd-card, htc-one-v

I am using HTC One V running ICS 4.0.3. The issue I often get is that my sd card is disconnected automatically for which I have to restart my device.
Secondly it takes a hell lot of time to load messages, why?

Comment: I've seen the former happen with a specific kind of sandisk card (the red and grey 'Ultra' 32 gb microsd cards). Does this happen with another SD card?

Comment: you mean to say that the issue is with memory card?

Comment: what about the lateness issue in loading the messages and contacts?

Comment: Well, I've not had issues with slow messages and contacts. I HAVE had one specific SD card give that trouble - this is a good reason to have one problem a question